# Typings duplicate declarations

Tags: typescript

I've set up three npm packages with the following dependencies

```
- angularjs-kit
    - ts-core
    - ts-data
        - ts-core
```

After I do

```
clone https://github.com/redound/angularjs-kit#dev-package
cd angularjs-kit
typings install
tsc
```

I get the following errors[image]

These errors are caused by duplicate `declare module '~ts-data~ts-core/lib/Data/Dictionary'` statements for example.

Are these packages not properly set up? Or am I just overlooking something?

Sources:

- https://github.com/redound/ts-core/tree/dev-package
- https://github.com/redound/ts-data/tree/dev-package
- https://github.com/redound/angularjs-kit/tree/dev-package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its a `typings` issue. I've created an issue report for further analysis : https://github.com/typings/typings/issues/378